# Debian installer hangs on network hardware detection due to Broadcom wlan chip

Tags: installation, debian, broadcom

I'm trying to net-install Debian testing (Jessie) on a laptop but I always get stuck during the network hardware detection.

Specifically, the last line I read in the syslog is that the firmware for the wlan chip (`bcm43xx-0.fw`) cannot be loaded.

For the installation I'm using a bootable USB drive on which I put the debian netinst iso.
I tried to flash the USB drive with both `usb-creator-gtk` and `dd` obtaining the same results.

I tried several debian installers:

- Jessie Alpha 1 installer (`debian-jessie-DI-a1-i386-netinst.iso`)
- the weekly build of the installer (`debian-testing-i386-netinst.iso`)
- Jessie Alpha 1 installer with non-free firmwares (`firmware-jessie-DI-a1-i386-netinst.iso`)
- the weekly build with non-free firmwares (`firmware-testing-i386-netinst.iso`)

In these last two installers I see that the firmware `bcm43xx-0.fw` actually exists down the `lib` path.

I also tried to run the installer with various boot options: `noapic nolapic`, `hw-detect/start_pcmcia=false`, `acpi=off` (each by its own and combined) but nothing changed.

I'm quite clueless.

This is my network hardware according to `lspci` on a running system (Ubuntu 11.04):

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

and this is the last page of the syslog of the debian installer just before it hangs:

```
main-menu[572]: INFO: Menu item 'ethdetect' selected
kernel: [         ...] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
kernel: [         ...] r8169 0000:05:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
kernel: [         ...] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4313, rev 0x01 and package 0x08
kernel: [         ...] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x24, class 0x0)
kernel: [         ...] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x18, class 0x0)
kernel: [         ...] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x11, class 0x0)
kernel: [         ...] r8169 0000:05:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-x
kernel: [         ...] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eth0: RTL8168e/8111e at 0xf801c00, e8:11:32:14:a6:ea, XID 0c200000 IRQ 43
kernel: [         ...] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
kernel: [         ...] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
net/hw-detect.hotplug: Detected hotpluggable network interface lo
kernel: [         ...] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain 
kernel: [         ...] Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1
kernel: [         ...] b43: probe of bcma0:0 failed with error -524
kernel: [         ...] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PMNLS ]
kernel: [         ...] brcmsmac bcma0:0: mfg 4bf core 812 rev 24 class 0 irq 16
net/hw-detect.hotplug: Detected hotpluggable network interface eth0
kernel: [         ...] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
net/hw-detect.hotplug: Detected hotpluggable network interface wlan0
check-missing-firmware: /dev/.udev/firmware-missing does not exist, skipping
check-missing-firmware: /run/udev/firmware-missing does not exist, skipping
check-missing-firmware: no missing firmware in /dev/.udev/firmware-missing /run/udev/firmware-missing
kernel: [         ...] brcmsmac bcma0:0: firmware: failed to load brcm/bcm/bcm43xx-0.fw (-2)
kernel: [         ...] brcmsmac bcma0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
kernel: [         ...] brcmsmac bcma0:0: Falling back to user helper
```

I wanted to try to unload/blacklist the kernel module for the Broadcom chip, but I didn't manage to do so. Would that work? How should I do that?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the wireless card in the BIOS configuration settings?

Comment: This is quite embarassing but it seems my laptop has nor a hardware switch nor a BIOS option to turn the wifi off. I'm tempted to open a new question about this. (The machine is a Samsung NP-RV511 by the way).

Comment: You should be able to get to the bios settings with the F2 key as stated here: http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=166758&modelname=NP-RV511I&modelcode=NP-RV511-A01US&session_id=&from_osc=

Comment: Of course, I do manage to get into the BIOS setup, but once there I can't find any option to turn off the wifi.

Comment: @etuardu I do face the same problem as you are and I think it's best not to use the netinstall cd/dvd of debian when installing. I am trying the full-dvd and I think that will bypass the installation as it won't need to detect the hardware. I'll fix the network/wifi issue after a full install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=681656

The work around is to go to a different shell: 
Press Alt-F2
type: `nano /bin/check-missing-firmware`

Under the first line of the script, add exit 0:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 0
```

Press Alt-F1 and return to the frozen screen and hit CTRL-C to kill and restart that script.  Do not select the conflicting harder for network setup, and you are good to go for now!

Comment: +1 to question and this answer. I can confirm this allows installation to bypass the freeze, which in my case occurred when installing even the latest ISO of Debian on a Dell Latitude D600. (I found the bug report too, but I would've been glad this answer was here, if I didn't!)

Comment: +1 this worked, but on my old Thinkpad T43 with the LinuxCNC installer (Wheezy, I think), it was Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2/F3... to switch consoles.

Answer (score 0):

Some related info for future readers of this thread; this does not offer a direct resolution to the problem posted but might offer another work-around if the problem persists like it did with me:

Encountered similar installation freeze at "detecting network hardware" with both Debian (9) & Ubuntu (16) on a old 32-bit i386 machine that continued to successfully run Windows Vista over years.

The installer did not make progress with several potential work-arounds including:

- the ones mentioned in this thread (installer did not respond to the keys)
- the use of boot options (per https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1326678):

  noapic nolapic acpi=off pci=noacpi irqpoll pnpbios=off
- use of the different installation wizards that Debian & Ubuntu offer (Advanced, Graphical, Textual etc.)

Ended up taking the VM route of installing Debian on the Windows Vista machine with VirtualBox; and the installation went thru well!

While use of a VM might not be feasible for all scenarios, it could be another work-around to consider.